# Special effects in jQuery don't work, caught error in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

http://content.screencast.com/users/DeviousDan/folders/Jing/media/3ff6788b-8cf1-4914-a92b-6953a3841092/2011-01-17_0822.png

That shows the error I'm getting, I get it no matter what jquery javascript file I'm using, just depends on the line, which happens to be:

```
this.pos = jQuery.easing[specialEasing || defaultEasing](this.state, n, 0, 1, this.options.duration);
```

The code that's getting the error:

```
$("#mainWrapper").show("bounce", { direction:"down", times:"3" }, 300);
```

Seems to happen with all .effect, however .slide and .fade works fine...

I don't get the error if I refer to it as mainWrapper, rather than #mainWrapper, however the effect still doesn't occur.

Unsure of why it's happening, any ideas? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you one and only one ID="mainWrapper" ?

Comment: Yes there is only a single div with the id mainWrapper.

Comment: show() is part of jQuery's base, but extending it by using direction and times needs jQuery's UI class as well. Are you including that in your source?

Comment: these: jquery-latest.js, ui/effects.core.js, ui/effects.bounce.js

Comment: In the docs http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce says that the "times" is integer, try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to load the jQuery UI library?

The "bounce" effect is a part of the jQueryUI lib, have a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce) for reference. JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtzsg/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove quotes in time property. It accepts integer value not string.

```
time:3
```

will solve problem I guess.